# expect.toBeDefined() is not a function with expect.toMatchObject()

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I want to test that an object returned matches what I expect with `jest`.

I'm trying this:

```
const desiredResult = {
  host: '192.168.1.1',
  port: expect.any(Number),
  delta: expect.toBeDefined()
}
expect(result).toMatchObject(desiredResult)
```

`jest` is saying that `.toBeDefined()` is not a function (but is fine with `.any(Number)`:

```
TypeError: expect.toBeDefined is not a function
  173 |       host: '192.168.1.1',
  174 |       port: expect.any(Number),
> 175 |       delta: expect.toBeDefined()
      |                     ^
  176 |     }
  177 |     expect(portCallback.mock.calls[0][0]).toMatchObject(desiredResult)
```

ect(desiredResult)

Comment: Did you try without the parentheses? Evidently the field exists, but isn't callable.

Comment: toBeUndefined is not to be used like that I think, it's expect.anything(). @PeterDanis answer is 100% correct.

Answer (score 1):

Use `expect.anything()` instead of `expect.toBeDefined()`.

It is like `expect.any()`, but does not require constructor as paramater and matches anything but `null` or `undefined`.

Please see https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/expect.html#expectanything